# Copying from ESI to Buffer to EDI

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I've been trying to wrap my head around how to do a memory copy via a buffer.

The parameters to my function are: `void* dest, void* src, size_t length`

I setup my function like so:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
push edi
push esi
push ebx

mov edi, [ebp+0x8] ; this is dest
mov esi, [ebp+0xc] ; this is src
mov ecx, [ebp+0x10] ; this is length
```

I'm at a bit of a loss on what to do next.  I understand I need to create a buffer because I could potentially have overlapping memory, but I'm unsure how to set my buffer up within my function.

Once I do, I'd imagine the code following would look something like (assuming `ebx` as the buffer):

```
mov ebx, [esi+4*ecx]
mov edi, [ebx]

pop edi
pop esi
pop ebx
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: For clarification, I'm putting one of my comments here: Essentially, I want to take the data stored in `esi` and move it to `edi`, but I also want to avoid a the situation where there might be memory overlap between `esi` and `edi`. I believe, using something like a buffer could accomplish this (am I using the term incorrectly?).

Comment: “memory copy via a buffer” is not precise enough of a description to understand what you want. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity, I'm very new to assembly.  Essentially, I want to take the data stored in `esi` and move it to `edi`, but I also want to avoid a the situation where there might be memory overlap between `esi` and `edi`.  I believe, using something like a buffer could accomplish this (am I using the term incorrectly?).

Comment: for `memcpy` after your setup you may do `rep movsb` to copy the memory block. But for overlapping regions `memcpy` is UB, then `memmove` should be used. Which will detect in which direction the overlap happens and copy either from start or from end of the block. In naive simple assembly you may end using `rep movsb` again, but with `std` (direction flag set to 1). Just add to pointers (size-1) value. That said such routine will not have best possible performance, that would need optimized code for different x86 CPU families, resolving alignment, etc.. So check some `rep movsb` tutorial/docs?

Comment: @Ped7g thanks for the comment, i'm in the early stages of learning so i'm not too concerned with optimizations.  If I'm understanding what you're saying  right, i can do `rep movs ebx, [esi]`?

Comment: no. [`movsb/movsw/movsd` (check link)](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_203.html) have fixed register usage, only target segment register may be overriden, but without segment prefix it will always copy byte/word/dword from `ds:esi` to `es:edi`. (and `rep` will use `ecx` as counter). So you can't change anything about it, `ebx` is unrelated.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying, I referenced: [this site](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Data_Transfer).  as long as `ecx` is set to the length of data, calling repo movsb will keep copying each byte of `esi` to `edi`?

Comment: uh.. I mixed it up, the source `ds` segment can be overridden, the target `es` is fixed, [here](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVS:MOVSB:MOVSW:MOVSD:MOVSQ.html) are docs mentioning even that. Anyway, as you are new to assembly, and it looks you are in protected mode (win or linux OS?), you probably don't have to deal with segment registers, and just run `rep movsb` with correct addresses and count, and DF. Also if you set DF to 1, clear it back to 0 (I think win32 has convention of DF=0, but it doesn't hurt to clear it just to be sure even when you want to copy from start to end)

Comment: Reposting my comment as you got in before I submitted mine =).  I think I see what you're saying, I referenced: [this site](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Data_Transfer).  as long as `ecx` is set to the length of data, calling `rep movsb` will keep copying each byte of `esi` to `edi`?

Comment: Yes, but I don't like your wording *"copying each byte of `esi`"*. More like each byte from memory pointed to by `esi` to memory pointed to by `edi`. `esi/edi` have their own 2x4 bytes directly on the CPU chip (not in DRAM chips), but those are not copied, those are used to store the address value and will be incremented `ecx` times. BTW, why don't you try? in data: `testdata db 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0`  ... in code: `lea esi,[testdata+1]` `lea edi,[esi+1]` `mov ecx,2` `cld` `rep movsb` and the memory content in debugger should change from `00 01 02 03 04 00` to `00 01 01 01 04 00` ... toy around...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things here. First, overlapping memory is generally handled by switching the direction in which the copy is done. You should first convince yourself that no matter how the two regions overlap, either starting at the lowest address in each block and copying from source to destination, incrementing the pointers for each byte; or starting at the highest address in each block and copying likewise, but then decrementing the pointers will work.

Using an intermediate buffer either requires tiling the copy against a fixed sized buffer, which still requires manipulating the direction, or calling e.g. malloc, which is mostly just slow, but also requires figuring out how to call a function from assembly.

To start with, I suggest writing out the direction conditional and two loops in C/C++ or similar. (A language with pointers helps.) I.e. write your own copy of memmove in C.

At that point, you need to translate an if statement, a loop, and copying from source to destination, into assembly. This is all fairly straight forward and there are some suggestions in the comments on how to use x86 instructions to do a counted loop for you. (Note that if using the built-in support, you need to know about the x86 direction flag, e.g. the CLD and STD instructions. I'd start by doing it long hand and then move to using the REP* support.)

One way to get a good handle on this is to write C/C++ code and use the assembly output flag to the compiler (e.g. -S on most UNIXy systems).

Comment: Thanks for your post!  I was taking a look at a simple memmove I implemented in C++ that started by copying a string starting from the last element first. `for (int i = n; i > 0; i++) dest[i] = src[i];`.  I made a simple loop in assembly `cmp ecx, 0`, `je bottom`, `mov eax, dword ptr [dest]`, `add eax, dword ptr [ebp-8]`, `dec ecx`, `jmp top`.  It's not quite working out for me yet.

Comment: Strings generally involve testing for the nul byte, which is fine, but tends to make the tradeoffs a bit different than a counted copy. It is perhaps surprising that something as simple as memcpy/memmove can result in so many tradeoffs in the implementation, but this tends to be the nature of performance optimization at this level. If you know you are copying large aligned buffers and have the full instruction set available, it probably pays to look at using the SIMD registers as well, but memmove typically cannot assume such.